# Reputation awards for edits - aren't they disproportionate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have had a few qualms about the awarding of reputation after editing. Let me state 2 of my cases:

1. [Inductive effect on stability of free radical](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81343/inductive-effect-on-stability-of-free-radical) and [revision link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/81343/2): In this question I had made a very trivial edit, just formatting using $\LaTeX$. Only 1 thing was changed and I got 2 rep for it. Looks fine!

But...

2. [How do you calculate the pH range for which one metal precipitates but the other stays in solution?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/179362/how-do-you-calculate-the-ph-range-for-which-one-metal-precipitates-but-the-other) and [revision link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/179362/3): For this question, it needed high amounts of time and repeated rechecking to get this question right. From an *apocalypse to the retina* I had made it somewhat readable.

Now the magnitude of these two edits are highly differentiable while the award is the same - just 2 reputation.

---

My suggestion is: can't we give the mods on this site to decide which edit deserves how much? Like award *zero* rep to highly trivial edits, while awarding an appreciable amount of reps for really good edits! What say everyone?

Comment: As a moderator, I am glad for any trivial thing that works automatically. Moderator is a volunteer task. Reputation points are not redeemable, so there is no reason for them to have a proportional relationship to effort, value to others, or anything else. They do have a psychological role of steering the community to do useful things, to a point. I'm hoping most of the effort on this site goes towards learning and explaining chemistry.

Comment: To add to earlier replies, this isn't even the place to ask for any changes in how reputation works. That would be https://meta.stackexchange.com/ I'm not suggesting going there with such request, though, unless it would be *very* well thought out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no trivial edits. There are edits that will be done by community members who have already earned the privilege to apply edits directly. These may seem trivial. They may do these as they do not have to be reviewed. The two reputation points you get ares only there for you to cross that threshold. Once you have the privilege you will not be awarded any points anymore.

Also, reputation points for edits will also vanish when the corresponding post is deleted. So please focus your efforts on the posts that are here to stay.